# Code like this in Python: a_list[i, j] = 3

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
a = 2
b = 3
a_list[a, b] = 4
```

I found some code like above in a python source file. I looked around in the source file, but found nothing about the definition of using turple as a list index. While I tried to intercept `i` in `UserList.__getiterm__(self, i) :` to check if `i` is a tuple, then do something. It really works. I want to know if intercepting parameter is the standard way to use tuple as list index.

**UPDATE:** I think it is a user-defined list, while I didn't find the definition.

Comment: Is `a_list` really a plain list here?

Comment: ^same with John. I don't think that's possible..

Comment: If it's a list, there should be a `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

Comment: Yeah, lists only allow indexing on integers.  However, dicts allow indexing on tuples.

Comment: Finally, I find it's not about list or dict. Any object can have the [] operator with its special usage (I mean, use int, tuple or any other type in []), provided that there is a __getitem__(self, i) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's a list. In your code, `a_list` is probably a dictionary. And yes, it's completely valid.

Example:

```
>>> c ={}
>>> c[2,3] = 4
>>> c
{(2,3):4)}
```

Another posibility is that this is a [numpy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

Hope this helps!

More on dictionaries: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries